# Essay vs Play a character

Tags: word-usage

Do we have any difference in the meanings of the following sentences:

> > Kathy got infatuated towards Brad because she was highly impressed by the personalities of the characters **essayed** by him.
> >
> > Kathy got infatuated towards Brad because she was highly impressed by the personalities of the characters **played** by him.

I checked the meanings of both of these words at Oxford dictionary.

> > play **VERB** ***with object*** Represent (a character) in a theatrical performance or a film.
> >
> > essay **VERB** Attempt or try.

So, from these meanings it appears that using the word **"play"** is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: I have literally never heard anyone use the word essayed. I'm a native English speaker and I had to Google it. so it's really not common. The second would be the preferred usage.

Comment: I agree with @Liam; I have heard the verb "to essay", but only in the context of overcoming some very difficult challenge, so it's not appropriate here.  I think it's also worth noting that one gets "infatuated **with**" someone, never "towards" someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Essay" is unusual in this sort of context, and if I read this I would interpret it that he was trying out those characters to see if they fit some purpose: without any context, I might think it meant that he was trying to trick her into someting.

"Play" does not have that suggestion.